# R dataframe: Select columns with title condition

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
Ad Bd Ce
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
```

And i want to select columns that contains 'd' in the name (i don't want to use column indexes).

I thought about using grepl(), but don't know how to specify the 'x' argument:

```
new_data <- old_data[,which(grepl("d",x))]
```

Comment: with `names(old_data)` - Also `which` is not really needed

Comment: It worked. Thanks @Sotos